# How to express the partial derivatives of a function?

Tags: partial-derivative

My calculus is a bit rusty and I would need a refresher on this:

Consider 2 functions $F$ and $G$. Both functions are $R \rightarrow R$. Consider a third function $y(u,v) = F(u)+G(v)$.

How can you show that  $\frac{\partial^2{y}}{\partial{u}\partial{v}}=0$.

I would need a hint on how to tackle this. Thanks!

Comment: I took the words "of a composite function" out because $y(u, v)$ is the sum of two function, not a composition of those functions.

Comment: OK my bad sorry.

Comment: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}(u, v) = G'(v)$. Does not depend on $u$. Hence $\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial u \partial v}(u, v) = 0$. Do you need something deeper than this?

Comment: Indeed as simple as that. Nearly feeling embarrassed to having asked the question :).

Comment: @user66081 Please do post an answer (transcribe your comment into an answer field, and post).  You were the first to note the issue.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: And I will accept it

Comment: @BigLudinski: Ok. Feel free to accept the existing answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y(u,v)=F(u)+G(v)\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = \frac {df}{du}\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = \frac {dg}{dv}$

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$ is a function of $u$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$ is a function of $v$

$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial u\partial v} = \frac{\partial }{\partial u}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} =\frac{\partial }{\partial v}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = 0$